# Python - Relative import from folder horizontal in file system

Tags: python, python-3.x

Diagram of file system:

```
└ main folder
   ├ folder 1
   │  └ module1
   └ folder 2
      └ module2
```

I want to import `module2` from `module1`. However, its horizontal to `module1` in the file tree. Is there an easy way to go about this without having to `import sys`, `os`, and etc.?

Thank you.

PS: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Where is your main script to execute?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where is your main script to execute, however, if you want to execute `module1` like

```
python module1.py
# or
python /PATH/TO/module1.py
```

you can simply do it like:

```
PYTHONPATH=/PATH/TO/folder_2:$PYTHONPATH python module1.py
```

`/PATH/TO/folder_2` can be relative to where you execute `python`.